# Stalker Portal - API Integration: Unauthorized Access

Tags: rest, api

I'm developing an application based on Stalker Portal API v3. I'm following the guidelines as given here: https://wiki.infomir.eu/eng/ministra-tv-platform/ministra-setup-guide/rest-api-v1#RESTAPIv1-Authentificationandauthorization

The problem I'm facing is authorization. I'm doing request to API URL with authorization header like the following (I've changed the actual base64 encoded string.):

```
Authorization: Basic YeRtd462Q==
```

But it always says:

```
{"status":"ERROR","results":"","error":"401 Unauthorized request"}
```

The hash is defined by

```
base64_encode("$admin:$password"); // written in php language.
```

How can it can be solved? Will it be different username/password than what I used to login at: http://127.0.0.1/stalker_portal/server/adm/

(I tried to add tags like: stalker, stalker-api but I don't have enough reputation to create these missing tags.)

Comment: I've not heard of either, but it looks like [Stalker has been renamed to Infomir](https://wiki.infomir.eu/eng/). Is that correct? New tags are fine (if a platform is substantial enough to warrant it) but we need to ensure they are correct and up-to-date.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is not well documented, I've managed to find the username/password that should be used. It is not the administrative login credentials, rather username & password that is set in file:

```
/path/to/stalker_portal/server/custom.ini
```

Here is the snippet of the configuration file:

```
[server_api]
; API required for tv archive, pvr and billing
enable_api = true

enable_soap_api = false

; For security reasons it is highly recommended to use HTTP authentication
api_auth_login = <username>
api_auth_password = <password>
```

That's it.
Using these in my request authorization header solves the problem. And don't forget to set `enable_api = true` to enable the REST API.